# i am writing following code in trigger of Navicat for mysql but its giving errors

Tags: mysql, navicat

this is my following code which is i wrote in Navicat for mysql.

```
Set @FileRef=0
FileRef:=select sum(id) from one;
```

this is above code of my trigger.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
DECLARE @FileRef INT;
SET @FileRef:= (select sum(id) from one);
```

Comment: i try but then also its giving error...that right syntax used near DECLARE...
This code i am writing in the definition of trigger in navicat for mysql

Comment: can you show the whole query? if the syntax says *near DECLARE*, it means that the error happens before declare.

Comment: i wrote only this above two lines only

Comment: no, you meantioned that you want to create a trigger right? i want to see the whole code starting from `CREATE TRIGGER...`

Comment: i upload image u can check in this url:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=20b1wus&s=6